# How to transform an object into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to transform an object into an array of objects, and remove the first unique key.

How can I make this:

```
{f56hdhgf54: {name: 'Sam', age: 34}, h65fg9f7d: {name: 'John', age: 42}}
```

into this:

```
[{name: 'Sam', age: 34}, {name: 'John', age: 42}]
```

so I can `.map` through it like this:

```
result.map((person) => {
   console.log(person.name, person.age)
})
```

Comment: Check [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get array of keys and then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change keys to values or in this case objects.

```js
var obj = {f56hdhgf54: {name: 'Sam', age: 34}, h65fg9f7d: {name: 'John', age: 42}}

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {
  return obj[e];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be using lodash map function to transform the data, i.e

```
let data = {
   "f56hdhgf54": {
      "name": "Sam",
       "age": 34
    },
    "h65fg9f7d": {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 42
    }
}


let result = _(data)
  .map((value, key) => (
    value
  ))


 // result
 [
   {
      "name": "Sam",
      "age": 34
   },
   {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 42
   }
]
```

You can use the Lodash Online tester https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz to test the code

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery solution of this question

```
var xyz = [];
    var abcd = {f56hdhgf54: {name: 'Sam', age: 34}, h65fg9f7d: {name: 'John', age: 42}}
    $.each(abcd,function(i,data){

    xyz .push(data);

    })
```

Comment: This is jQuery? I can't use that :)

Comment: Then You can iterate using for loop i am habitual of using jquery iterator

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @MichaelParker Yes you are right actually i feel easiness in code to understanding where jquery simplifies lot of complex code in javascript

Comment: What I mean is that your answer only gives code, but not an explanation for **why** this code works.  Code-only answers are considered to be low-quality here on StackOverflow.